# Im getting an error in chrome saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < line and it displays that just under <script> of javascript file

Tags: jquery

Im getting an error in chrome saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < line and it displays that just under  of javascript file

This is my html file that is trying to run the javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<script src="Javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Javascripts/orderform.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='website.css'>
</head>
<body>
<table> <table border="0"> <tr>
<tr> <td> First Name:     </td> <td> <input type="text" name="firstName">  </td> </tr>                   
<br> <br>
<tr> <td> Last Name:      </td> <td> <input type="text" name="lastName">   </td> </tr>    
<br> <br>
<tr> <td> Dorm Name:      </td> <td> <input type="text" name="dormName">   </td> </tr>   
<br> <br>
<tr> <td> Room Number:    </td> <td> <input type="text" name="roomNumber"> </td> </tr><br>                       
<tr> <td> Pizza Type:     </td> <td> <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Cheese">           
Cheese <br>
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni <br>
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Buffalo Chicken"> Buffalo Chicken </td>


<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Cheese" id="extraCheese"> Cheese <br>
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Buffalo Chicken" id="extraBuffaloChicken">    
Buffalo Chicken <br>
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Pepperoni" id="extraPepperoni"> Pepperoni <br>
<input type="button" name="extraPizza" id="extraPizza">

<tr> <td> Number of Pizza's:  <td>   <input type="text" name="pizzaNumber"> </td> </tr>              
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br> <br>            <tr> <td> </td> <td> <div                  
align="center"> <input type="submit" </tr> </td> </div

</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my external javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery $("#extraCheese").hide()
});
</script>
```

Comment: A screenshot would be better in this case. Did you by chance, copy and paste your script from a JSFiddle? Also, did you notice your HTML is malformed? `<input type="submit" </tr> </td> </div`

Comment: would you like me to take a screen shot and no i didnt copy anything

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? And your script needs to come *after* the jQuery include.

Comment: Note: The # in `document.getElementById('#extraCheese')` should not be there

Comment: you include the library by making a .js file and linking it right? and thank you @MatthewDean i thought you had to put that because thats its id.

Comment: Also, if you are going to use jQuery, then use jQuery. You can replace the `getElementById` line with the jQuery `$("#extraCheese").hide()`

Comment: @PhilPilon: As ahren said, the order is important. You have to include jQuery *before* any scripts that use jQuery.

Comment: alright i changed everything said however i still have the error

Comment: @ahren no most not have copied right, but that doesn't have to with my javascript. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I don't think putting a form in the head is legit...I may be wrong though.

Comment: Also, you should have a close tag on this line `<link rel='stylesheet' href='website.css'>` like this `<link rel='stylesheet' href='website.css'/>`